# Can't connect Postgres container with Django container on Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have two images: 1. PostgreSQL, 2. Django application.
I am trying to connect django with postgres via networking
Here is my *DATABASE_URL*

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:somepassword@0.0.0.0:5432/music
```

and my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.1"
services:
        db:
                image: postgres
                environment:
                        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
                        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: qweytr21
                        POSTGRES_DB: music
                ports:
                        - 5432:5432
        web:
                build: music-releases/
                ports:
                        - 8000:8000
                depends_on:
                        - db          
                command: pipenv run python manage.py migrate
```

So when i run **docker-compose up**. Postgres shows that it is listening this address

```
listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
```

But Django (psycopg2-binary) shows error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

As you can see psycopg searchs true host and port and postgres also is listening on that host and port. I have already searched for another answer but they don't work.
Any help PLEEEASE!!!

Comment: are you using `db` as your postgres host in django?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments from Oli

- you have to use `db` as hostname for your database connection
- both containers should be in the same network so Create docker network using this command `docker network create <your network>`
- add to your docker-compose file the network for both containers, you can follow this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks)